# Not getting any output. First time using filestream in C++

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program that uses filestreams and I'm not getting any output at all when I run it.

Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<cctype>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string word, search, inputfilename, outputfilename;
   ifstream inf;
   int wordcount = 0;
   int charcount = 0;
   cout << "Enter input file name" << endl;
   cin >> inputfilename;
   inf.open(inputfilename.c_str());
   cout << "Enter search string" << endl;
   cin >> search;
   inf >> word;

   while(inf)
   {
      wordcount++;
   }

   inf.close();
   cout << "Words: " << wordcount << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

The input file I am using is just a paragraph that contains a a few sentences.

I'm not sure what is wrong with my code so far, help is appreciated.

Comment: Just accept the answer that helped, then nobody will worry about adding another answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an infinite loop. Try this:

```
while (inf >> word)
{
 wordcount++;
}
```

Comment: Ah, whoops. Okay, I just added inf >> word at the end of the loop and it's working. Thanks ooga.

Comment: Okay, thanks Deplud, I'll accept Ooga's answer when in 4 minutes when it lets me.